# The right use of jQuery? Owl carousel

Tags: javascript, optimization, owl-carousel

For my project I use the OwlCarousel. http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#more-demos

I managed to get 3 carousels on my page. But I think the page is getting to slow. Is there a possibility that I make to many steps?

Actually I don't need to read the json file because I store it in the `localStorage` one page before. But I didn't know how to delete it out without corrupting the code.

So the main question is how to make just one jQuery call to fill all 3 carousels?

---

This is the code I use to call the carousel:

```
<div id="dodatni1" style="visibility:hidden" >
  <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel" ></div>
</div> 

<div  id="dodatni2" style="visibility:hidden" >
  <div id="owl-demo2" class="owl-carousel" ></div>
</div> 

<div  id="dodatni3" style="visibility:hidden" >
  <div id="owl-demo3" class="owl-carousel" ></div>
</div>
```

And this is the carousel code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    jsonPath : 'json/fakeData.json',
    jsonSuccess : customDataSuccess,
    lazyLoad : false
  });

  function customDataSuccess(data){
    var content = "";
    var stevec = 0;
    var dolzina = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('dolzina'));
    for(var j=0;j<dolzina;j++){
      if (stevec<10){
        var imgg ="http://www.spleticna.si/images/"+localStorage.getItem('imga'+j);
        var doza = localStorage.getItem('dozaa'+j);
        if (doza == 3239){
          content += "<a href=\"produkt.html?id=" + j + "&slider=a\" target='frejm' onclick='pokaziiframe()'><img src=\"" + imgg + "\" onError=this.src='napaka.png'></a>"
          stevec=stevec+1;
        }
      }
    }
    $("#owl-demo").html(content);
  }


});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-demo2").owlCarousel({
    jsonPath : 'json/fakeData.json',
    jsonSuccess : customDataSuccess,
    lazyLoad : false
  });

  function customDataSuccess(data){
    var content = "";
    var stevec = 0;
    var dolzina = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('dolzina'));
    for(var j=0;j<dolzina;j++){
      if (stevec<10){
        var imgg = "http://www.spleticna.si/images/" + localStorage.getItem('imga'+j);
        var doza = localStorage.getItem('dozaa'+j);
        if (doza == 2615){
          content += "<a href=\"produkt.html?id=" + j + "&slider=b\" target='frejm' onclick='pokaziiframe()'><img src=\"" + imgg + "\" onError=this.src='napaka.png'></a>"
          stevec=stevec+1;
        }
      }
    }
    $("#owl-demo2").html(content);
  }


});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-demo3").owlCarousel({
    jsonPath : 'json/fakeData.json',
    jsonSuccess : customDataSuccess,
    lazyLoad : false
  });

  function customDataSuccess(data){
    var content = "";
    var stevec = 0;
    var dolzina = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('dolzina'));
    for(var j=0;j<dolzina;j++){
      if (stevec<10){
        var imgg = "http://www.spleticna.si/images/" + localStorage.getItem('imga'+j);
        var doza = localStorage.getItem('dozaa'+j);
        if (doza == 3140){
          content += "<a href=\"produkt.html?id=" + j + "&slider=c\" target='frejm' onclick='pokaziiframe()'><img src=\"" + imgg + "\" onError=this.src='napaka.png'></a>"
          stevec=stevec+1;
        }
      }
    }
    $("#owl-demo3").html(content);
  }

});
```

Comment: My first thought is, you don't need to embed `$(document).ready` inside itself; the purpose for that is to listen to the DOM ready event and run the code inside the function when that happens. The DOM will fire once for you, that's all you need for all three carousels. Also, see if you can spot common code between them (customDataSuccess, perhaps) and define that once. (Do you need a custom JSON routine?)

Comment: Yes i know JQuery is slow ... but the carousel was written using jQuery and I'm a begginer in development ...  also its my last time using carousels ...

carpeliam :   i really dont need the JSON routine because I stored all data one page before this one...  but I dont know how do delete it... anything I tryed resulted in code not working ...
so if you know the answer :) please tell me :)

Comment: Why redefining customDataSuccess thrice and also all carousel can be initiated in single document.ready function

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much speed you could get but you can rewrite your JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Assuming they all use the same data source/settings?
    $("#owl-demo3,#owl-demo2,#owl-demo1").owlCarousel({
        jsonPath : 'json/fakeData.json',
        jsonSuccess : customDataSuccess,
        lazyLoad : false
    });

    function customDataSuccess(data){
        var content = "";
        var stevec = 0;
        var dolzina = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('dolzina'));
        for(var j=0;j<dolzina;j++){
            if (stevec<10){
                var imgg = "http://www.spleticna.si/images/" + localStorage.getItem('imga'+j);
                var doza = localStorage.getItem('dozaa'+j);
                if (doza == 3140){
                    content += "<a href=\"produkt.html?id=" + j + "&slider=c\" target='frejm' onclick='pokaziiframe()'><img src=\"" + imgg + "\" onError=this.src='napaka.png'></a>"
                    stevec=stevec+1;
                }
            }
       }
       $("#owl-demo3").html(content);
   }
});
```